# Combining columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to do the following:
 I have a table with ename, job, deptno, and sal. I am trying to initiate a query that returns the top earners of each department. I have done this with grouping and a subquery. However, I also want to display the average sal by deptno. So the following would be the result:

```
"ename"  "dept"  "sal"  "average of dept"
sal      20      1000   500   
kelly    30      2000   800 
mika     40      3000   400
```

this might be impossible since the average does not associate with the other rows.

any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks. I am using Oracle 10g to run my queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. The only trick is that if you have several employees with the maximum salary in a department, it will show all of them.

```
SELECT t.ename, t.deptno, mx.sal as sal, mx.avg_sal as avg_sal
FROM tbl t, 
  (SELECT MAX(sal) AS sal, AVG(sal) AS avg_sal, deptno
   FROM tbl
   GROUP BY deptno) mx
WHERE t.deptno = mx.deptno AND t.sal = mx.sal
```

Comment: wow this is great. this worked!!! Even my own sql instructor told me that the query was impossible. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [analytic functions](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#i81407):

```
WITH RankedAndAveraged AS (
  SELECT
    ename,
    dept,
    sal,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY dept ORDER BY sal DESC) AS rnk,
    AVG(sal) OVER (PARTITION BY dept) AS "average of dept"
  FROM atable
)
SELECT
  ename,
  dept,
  sal,
  "average of dept"
FROM RankedAndAveraged
WHERE rnk = 1
```

This may return more than one employee per department if all of them have the same maximum value of `sal`. You can replace `RANK()` with `ROW_NUMBER()` if you only want one person per department (in which case you could also further extend `ORDER BY` by specifying additional sorting criteria to pick the top item, otherwise it will be picked randomly from among those with the maximum salary).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Oracle, haven't used it in about 10 years, but something like this should be possible:

```
SELECT
  ename, deptno, sal,
  (SELECT AVG(T2.sal)
    FROM tbl T2
    WHERE T2.deptno = T.deptno
  ) AS average_of_dept
FROM tbl T
GROUP BY deptno
HAVING sal = MAX(sal)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. For some reason though the query is not working. I forgot to mention that there is only one table (emp) where all the data is.

Comment: @user1006446 He is selecting from only one table. BTW, never say just "it's not working". Always specify **how** it is not working - i.e. is there an error message, or perhaps the query result is incorrect etc...